# rxjs mock response into a pipe/tap

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, rxjs, karma-jasmine

I'm working on unit tests for an Angular 7.1 app.  We use rxjs 6.3.3.  My component has a service call that looks like this.

```
this.registrationservice
            .createAccount(model)
            .pipe(
                tap(
                    (resp: {}) => {
                        this.router.navigate([url]);
                    },
                    (error: any) => {
                        this.isError = true;
                        this.registrationState.resetData();
                        this.resetUrl = this.registrationState.verifyStepState(RegistrationStepName.confirm);
                    }
                ),
                finalize(() => {
                    this.isLoading = false;
                })
            )
            .subscribe();
```

When I try to return an error response it never gets into the .tap error handler?  How do I mock this out?  Here is my test

```
it("Register User error", fakeAsync(() => {
        let errorResponse = {
            statusCode: "400",
            error: "no good"
        };
        userRegisterSvcStub.createAccount.and.throwError(ErrorObservable.create(errorResponse));
        let model = new UserRegisterModel({ userregistrationtypeid: modelProviderType.id, ...modelNpi, ...modelCreateAccount });
        registerDataStateSpy.getRegisterUserData.and.returnValue(model);
        registerDataStateSpy.verifyStepState.and.returnValue("../beginning");
        component.ngOnInit();
        tick();
        expect(mockRouter.navigate).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(component.resetUrl).toEqual("../beginning");
    }));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Giving more details to Christian's answer...

From the way you are using it, I assume `userRegisterSvcStub` is a spy object and `createAccount()` is a spy method on that object?  If so then the code you are currently using here:

```
userRegisterSvcStub.createAccount.and.throwError(ErrorObservable.create(errorResponse));
```

will actually throw an error using the jasmine `throwError()` method, as documented [here](https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Spies:_%3Ccode%3Eand.throwError%3C/code%3E).

What I think you want is to use the rxjs throwError as Christian suggested.  To do this your code would look something like this:

```
import { throwError } from 'rxjs'; // up with your other imports

userRegisterSvcStub.createAccount.and.returnValue(throwError(errorResponse));
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately it still goes into the "sucess" block in the tap...trying to figure out what I can give the mock to make it recognize that it is an error not sucess

Comment: My bad..This works!...one of my other spy calls still had the previous data mocked so it wasn't reaching my code....need more coffee...cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the throwError operator from rxjs to create an Observable that immediatly throws whatever you passed to the function.